# How do I return a string in a Jest mocked component's render method without Flow complaining?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, flowtype

I'm mocking a React component in a Jest test, and flow is complaining:

```
[flow] string (This type is incompatible with the expected return type of React$Element)
```

How do I allow for this?  Here's my code:

```
jest.mock('../../../../ui-components/lib/Forms/TextField', () => {
  const React = require('react');
  const TextField = class extends React.Component {
      render() {
          return 'TextField'; // Flow complains here
      }
  };
  return TextField;
});
```

EDIT:

For those googling, this is what I did:

```
jest.mock('../../../../ui-components/lib/Forms/TextField', () => {
  const React = require('react');
  const TextField = class extends React.Component {
      render() {
          return <div />;
      }
  };
  return TextField;
});
```

I was operating under an incorrect assumption that enzyme's shallow wrapper wouldn't locate the component unless I was returning a string here.  I'll be honest, I don't recall why I thought that, as it seems absurd now.

I've marked the answer to my original question below, as that was correct if I hadn't taken this better approach.  The use of // $FlowFixMe

Comment: Why do you need it to return a raw string? Why not `null` or `div` or whatever?

Comment: You're correct, I should use div in this case.  The issue I thought I was having is that I thought my test was failing to locate the component in the shallow render wrapper unless I used that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're doing this, but if you're certain about it, you  can add a `//$FlowFixMe` comment above the line that errors.

`//$FlowFixMe` [Defines a magical comment that suppresses any Flow errors on the following line](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex)

Hope this helps.